# Greying out disabled items that can be enabled vs items that cannot be enabled

Tags: usability, user-expectation, usability-testing, user-centered-design, experience

so I am working on a device management system and to add a new device to a group you must input some info into a form. Some items, you must click a check box in order to enable the dropdown, while some items you cant edit no matter what, but the information must still be present.

[image]

As you can see, what you enable "data encrypt", the dropdown is enabled and you can select from the list, while under VNET addr/len, you cannot enable those forms no matter what, but I still need the information available for the user to see. Now, I dont want the users to assume that there is a way to enable the VNET Addr boxes, but I cant think of a way to visually show that information without having a greyed out box. This creates confusion since the user may try clicking around to enable those boxes. Any tips on how to display this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the non-editable items display as text or numbers, with no disabled-like signifiers.

[image]

If I understand your question, it looks like you have a visual treatment that doesn't differentiate in a form between editable (but disabled) items vs. uneditable items. Treating them as data in display mode can provide some differentiation.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!